# MYSQL Field contains invalid characters, how to remove it - Got the Solution

Tags: mysql

This field name is Brand, Defined as UTF8 Characterset

Value is:

- Câ€ Cell Premium Battery

--> It displaying like this.

See there is a character â€,  I tried to replace that value of  â€  with Spaces, but its not happening.

I tried REPLACE(Brand,'â€',''),  But i am getting the same string.

Any suggestion on how to remove that.

I am not trying to change the table. The value in the table its present like that                                                      SELECT Brand, REPLACE( Brand,  'â€',  '' ) 
FROM INFO
WHERE ASIN =  'B001RQD01W'                                                                                           I got the result like below,  I.e  that character not removed                                               "

- Câ€ Cell Premium Battery

"
"

- Câ€ Cell Premium Battery

"   For both same result.

Even though it displayed as Câ€,  But in column value of the table it stored as C”.  Hence the below step worked. REPLACE( Brand,  'C”',  '' )

Regards
Vikram

Comment: Can you please show us exactly what statements you have tried to use to remove the characters? `REPLACE()` doesn't necessarily make any changes to the database.

Comment: Are those characters actually in the database or is that what is returned in the query response? If those characters are coming from the query, can you show us the query?

Comment: UPDATE table SET Brand=REPLACE(Brand,'â€','').But you probably need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I am not trying to change the table. The value in the table its present like that                                                      SELECT Brand, REPLACE( Brand,  'â€',  '' ) 
FROM INFO
WHERE ASIN =  'B001RQD01W'                                            I got the result like below,  I.e  that character not removedl                                                "<UL><LI>Câ€ Cell Premium Battery </UL>"
"<UL><LI>Câ€ Cell Premium Battery </UL>"   For both same result.

Comment: Are you viewing the query result in MySQL Workbench? In a web browser? In an IDE?

Comment: After exporting result in CSV i am seeing

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this one record, why try replacing an already bad string, just force an update... something like

```
update Info 
   set brand = 'CAE Cell Preimium Battery'
   where ASIN = 'B001RQD01W'
```

Now, I would not do this if it was impacting more than one row, or do multiple individual based on the limited condition that 'bad' characters are in the string, but Just force the new value (not sure if 'CAE' is what is should be, but just an example)